# Fontspec not searching in TEXINPUTS

Tags: fontspec, texinputs

I'm writing an application in which I want to generate pdf file using xelatex. The process of generating the pdf file from tex file takes place in a tmp file however data files such as fonts and images are stored in a folder. 
To avoid writing the folder address in tex file I added this folder to my TEXINPUTS. Now tex can find the images in this folder but when I use a font which is inside this folder it's unable to find it. I'm using xepersian which uses fontspec. I tried using fontspec directly but it failed as well. 
Here is a document I tried to compile for test:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{XB Zar2}
\begin{document}\end{document}
```

There is a ttf file named XB Zar2 inside a folder named Zar in the current directory. So I used:

```
export TEXINPUTS=./Zar//:
```

May someone tell me how to handle this? Thank you.

Comment: Fonts for `fontspec` are looked for in `OPENTYPEFONTS` and `TTFONTS`, not in `TEXINPUTS`

Comment: Why not post it as an answer? May you tell me what each of them is for? I mean what is their difference?

Comment: It seems OPENTYPEFONTS is not working for me. However TTFONTS works and it seems it works for both opentype fonts and truetype fonts. Isn't there a more global variable? One that covers TEXINPUTS and TTFONTS both?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fonts for `fontspec` are looked for using the `OPENTYPEFONTS` and `TTFONTS` variables. The setting in `texmf.cnf` is

```
% TrueType outline fonts.
TTFONTS = .;$TEXMF/fonts/{truetype,opentype}//;$OSFONTDIR//

% OpenType outline fonts.
OPENTYPEFONTS = .;$TEXMF/fonts/{opentype,truetype}//;$OSFONTDIR//
```

The difference between the two variables is evident. The variable `OSFONTDIR` shouldn't need being set.

If you have your personal files in, say

```
~/personalfilesandfonts/
```

then you should set

```
export TEXINPUTS=~/personalfilesandfonts//:
export TTFONTS=~/personalfilesandfonts//:
export OPENTYPEFONTS=~/personalfilesandfonts//:
```

There's no way for setting a “catch all” variable, because the three are used for very different purposes.

If the files are in a subdirectory of the current directory, as in your example, use

```
export TEXINPUTS=./Zar//:
export TTFONTS=./Zar//:
export OPENTYPEFONTS=./Zar//:
```